# How to Mock postgresql (pg) in node.js using jest

Tags: node.js, postgresql, unit-testing, jestjs, sinon

I am new in node.js. I am writing code in node.js for postgresql using `pg` and `pg-native` for serverless app. I need to write unit test for it. I am unable to mock `pg` client using jest or sinon.

My actual code is like this

```
const { Client } = require('pg');
export const getAlerts = async (event, context) => {

  const client = new Client({
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    port: process.env.PORT
  });

  await client.connect();

  try {
    const result = await client.query(`SELECT * FROM public.alerts;`);
    console.log(result.rows);
    client.end();
    return success({ message: `${result.rowCount} item(s) returned`, data: result.rows, status: true });

  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e.stack);
    client.end();
    return failure({ message: e, status: false });
  }

};
```

How to mock `pg` client here?

Comment: I use sinon. What part of `Client` do you want to mock? Generally it's something like `sinon.replace(pg.Client.prototype, 'query', sinon.fake.resolves({rows:[]});`

Comment: I want to mock ```client.connect()``` and ```client.query```

Comment: How to mock the pg events(pg.on)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is the unit test solution using `jestjs`:

`index.js`:

```js
const { Client } = require('pg');
const { success, failure } = require('./handler');

export const getAlerts = async (event, context) => {
  const client = new Client({
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    port: process.env.PORT,
  });

  await client.connect();

  try {
    const result = await client.query(`SELECT * FROM public.alerts;`);
    console.log(result.rows);
    client.end();
    return success({ message: `${result.rowCount} item(s) returned`, data: result.rows, status: true });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e.stack);
    client.end();
    return failure({ message: e, status: false });
  }
};
```

`hander.js`:

```js
export function success(data) {}
export function failure(data) {}
```

`index.spec.js`:

```js
import { getAlerts } from './';
import { Client } from 'pg';
import { success, failure } from './handler';

jest.mock('pg', () => {
  const mClient = {
    connect: jest.fn(),
    query: jest.fn(),
    end: jest.fn(),
  };
  return { Client: jest.fn(() => mClient) };
});

jest.mock('./handler.js', () => {
  return {
    success: jest.fn(),
    failure: jest.fn(),
  };
});

describe('59540432', () => {
  let client;
  beforeEach(() => {
    client = new Client();
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
  it('should success', async () => {
    client.query.mockResolvedValueOnce({ rows: [], rowCount: 0 });
    await getAlerts();
    expect(client.connect).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(client.query).toBeCalledWith('SELECT * FROM public.alerts;');
    expect(client.end).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(success).toBeCalledWith({ message: '0 item(s) returned', data: [], status: true });
  });

  it('should failure', async () => {
    const mError = new Error('dead lock');
    client.query.mockRejectedValueOnce(mError);
    await getAlerts();
    expect(client.connect).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(client.query).toBeCalledWith('SELECT * FROM public.alerts;');
    expect(client.end).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(failure).toBeCalledWith({ message: mError, status: false });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59540432/index.spec.js (11.792s)
  59540432
    ✓ should success (16ms)
    ✓ should failure (5ms)

  console.log src/stackoverflow/59540432/index.js:3131
    []

  console.error src/stackoverflow/59540432/index.js:3155
    Error: dead lock
        at /Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/src/stackoverflow/59540432/index.spec.js:39:20
        at step (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/src/stackoverflow/59540432/index.spec.js:33:23)
        at Object.next (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/src/stackoverflow/59540432/index.spec.js:14:53)
        at /Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/src/stackoverflow/59540432/index.spec.js:8:71
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at Object.<anonymous>.__awaiter (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/src/stackoverflow/59540432/index.spec.js:4:12)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/src/stackoverflow/59540432/index.spec.js:38:24)
        at Object.asyncJestTest (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmineAsyncInstall.js:102:37)
        at resolve (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:43:12)
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at mapper (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:26:19)
        at promise.then (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:73:41)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        14.109s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59540432

Comment: to be honest I've somehow got a different solution, but this is interesting and cool. I am also mocking out the console until I replace it with a decent logging library

Comment: Excellent answer. Especially how to mock behavior of query() in each test. From jest mock documentation I could not understand how to do it.

Answer (score 12):

Its an old question, but here is a new answer:

You can have a look at [pg-mem](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-mem), a library I released recently which emulates an in-memory postgres instance.

It supports most of the usual SQL queries (but will fail on less frequent syntaxes - file an issue if you encounter such a situation).

I wrote an article about it [here](https://dev.to/oguimbal/how-to-really-unit-test-code-that-uses-a-db-3gmg)

For your use case (how to use it with `pg`), see the [this wiki section](https://github.com/oguimbal/pg-mem/wiki/Libraries-adapters#-node-postgres-pg)

Answer (score 5):

This is my set up

```js
const { Pool } = require('pg');

// setup for to mock pg
jest.mock('pg', () => {
  const mPool = {
    connect: function () {
      return { query: jest.fn() };
    },
    query: jest.fn(),
    end: jest.fn(),
    on: jest.fn(),
  };
  return { Pool: jest.fn(() => mPool) };
});

describe('test for handle relay action', () => {
  let pool;
  // before each test case
  beforeEach(() => {
    pool = new Pool();
  });
  // clean up after each test case done
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  test('should test', async () => {
    \* implement your test here *\
    
    pool.query.mockResolvedValue({ rows: [] });
    expect(pool.query).toBeCalledTimes(3);
    expect(pool.query).toHaveBeenCalledWith("check some texts");
    expect(pool.query).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.anything());
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, man, thank you very much indeed

Answer (score 0):

I do not advise anyone uses this, and there may be some errors, but it's getting me 100% unit test coverage for-now...

It covers the Pool API with callbacks instead of the Client API everyone seems to have focused on.

```
jest.mock('pg')
const { Pool } = require('pg')
const mockPgPoolOn = jest.fn((_event, callback) => { callback() })
const mockPgPoolConnectClientClose = jest.fn(() => {})
const mockPgPoolConnectQueryDoneFn = jest.fn(() => {
  mockPgPoolConnectClientClose()
})
let mockPgPoolConnectErr = null
let mockPgPoolConnectQueryErr = null
let mockPgPoolConnectQueryResult = null
const mockPgPoolConnectQuery = jest.fn((_text, _params, callback) => {
  callback(
    mockPgPoolConnectQueryErr,
    mockPgPoolConnectQueryResult
  )
})
const mockPgPoolConnectClient = jest.fn(() => {
  return {
    query: mockPgPoolConnectQuery,
    on: mockPgPoolOn,
    close: mockPgPoolConnectClientClose
  }
})
const mockPgPoolConnect = jest.fn((callback) => {
  callback(
    mockPgPoolConnectErr,
    mockPgPoolConnectClient(),
    mockPgPoolConnectQueryDoneFn
  )
})
let mockPgPoolQueryErr = null
let mockPgPoolQueryResult = null
const mockPgPoolQuery = jest.fn((_text, _params, callback) => {
  callback(mockPgPoolQueryErr, mockPgPoolQueryResult)
})
Pool.mockImplementation((_config) => {
  return {
    connect: mockPgPoolConnect,
    query: mockPgPoolQuery,
    on: mockPgPoolOn
  }
})

const db = require('./index') // My module that uses require('pg')
```

I also have handlers to clean-up as this is all before I start defining anything...

```
afterEach(() => {
  mockPgPoolQuery.mockClear()
  mockPgPoolConnect.mockClear()
  // ...

  mockPgPoolQueryErr = null
  mockPgPoolConnectErr = null
  mockPgPoolConnectQueryErr = null
  mockPgPoolConnectQueryResult = null
  mockPgPoolQueryResult = null
  // ...
})
```

It seems like a lot of work and like I've said, although it gives me the coverage that 1:1 matches observed usage, it seems like a lot.

I'm using the callback API as it's what was documented by the pg dependency... Not loving it so far.